# How does Google detect nationality/language while I am in another country and in incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, privacy

I am Danish, but currently located in Turkey.
I opened an Incognito window to test a project, and Google shows up in Danish. My user agent does not contain a language - as far as I am aware - and Geolocation puts me in Turkey. How does Google know that I speak Danish? Does Chrome send some sort of information about the language that I speak, even though I am in another country and in Incognito?

Comment: Are you signed into chrome? If you inspect the http request, does it have an Accept-Language header that cites danish?

Comment: Signed into Chrome, yes. It does not show up whilst Incognito, however.

Comment: Perhaps being signed in makes chrome send accept-language header.. press F12 to get into developer tools, make a request and look at the network table.. it allows to inspect the headers of the request

Comment: @CaiusJard yup! My browser is sending a `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header with the value `da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`. That would be the solution.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Xwouf3C.png [edit: oops, you already found it]

Comment: Thank you anyways, @Ryan

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Google remembers your IP address and most frequently submitted requests from it. This is what is happening to me, since I'm always going through the same VPN, either in incognito mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check the browser language:

```
navigator.browserLanguage: browser language
```

Internet Explorer supports the following:

```
navigator.browserLanguage: browser language
navigator.systemLanguage: Windows system language
navigator.userLanguage: Windows user-specific language
```

Maybe the settings of your browser are on your native language.

Comment: This is what I get on mybrowserinfo.com:
    `Language:English`
    `System Language:Not detectable with this browser`
    `User Language:en-us`

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome sends a `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`-header with the value `da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`. This would allow pretty much any site that inspects headers to detect language used.

It prioritises da-DK (Danish), then en-US (American English), and lastly en (I would assume Standard English or British English).

Thanks to [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard) for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3MdsRLXtGi0

In short, update the order of the list of the language that you've denoted as spoken.

PS I've nearly gone mad looking for a solution for this issue. A lot of tips are out there, all were misleading. I have even deleted completely my Chrome history. Finally got rid of Finnish though it's an amazing language :)